# Comparing dates within groups

Tags: r

I have a data frame with data split into groups with each row in each group given a code.
I want the dates of everything within the group to be compared to the date given to 'a'.
So for group 1, 'a' has a date of '2022-01-01', 'b' has a date of '2022-01-03' which is after the date of 'a' and therefore 'after' is written in the comment field (which shows the expected outcomes of the data in this example).
I want to write code that populates the 'comment' field based on the rule above.

```
group<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
code<-c("a","b","c","d","a","b","c")
date<-c('2022-01-01','2022-01-03', '2021-12-15', '2022-05-01','2021-06-01', '2022-04-04','2022-05-10')
comment<-c(NA, "after","before","after",NA,"after","after")

data<-data.frame(group, code, date, comment, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Can anyone suggest any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(comment2 = case_when(
        first(as.Date(date)) == as.Date(date) ~ NA_character_,
        first(as.Date(date)) > as.Date(date) ~ "before",
        TRUE ~ "after")) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 7 × 5
#  group code  date       comment comment2
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   
#1     1 a     2022-01-01 NA      NA      
#2     1 b     2022-01-03 after   after   
#3     1 c     2021-12-15 before  before  
#4     1 d     2022-05-01 after   after   
#5     2 a     2021-06-01 NA      NA      
#6     2 b     2022-04-04 after   after   
#7     2 c     2022-05-10 after   after
```

I'm creating a new `comment2` column to explicitly show that it reproduces your expected output in column `comment`.

This assumes that

1. There is always an `"a"` `code`, and
2. Codes are ordered `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` by `group` (making `"a"` the first `code` in every `group`).

If codes are *not* ordered (but there is always an `"a"` `code`), you can do

```r
data %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(comment2 = case_when(
        as.Date(date)[code == "a"] == as.Date(date) ~ NA_character_,
        as.Date(date)[code == "a"] > as.Date(date) ~ "before",
        TRUE ~ "after")) %>%
    ungroup()
```